# c# array outputs 0 when it isnt specified

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am trying to output the odd and even numbers of an array, i have got it all working but for some reason when i create a foreach loop and output each number that is odd/even it starts with a zero?

The way it is setup that the user inputs 10 numbers with a comma in between each letter (Starts as a string) and then it removes the comma and converts the numbers into an int and places it in an int array, to then be used in the other class. I input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1 to test it.

```
    Odds(ai.Odds);
    Evens(ai.Evens);



    Console.ReadKey();
}
    public static void Odds(int[] odds)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nOdds:");
        foreach (var odd in odds)
        {
            Console.Write(odd + " ");   
        }
    }

public static void Evens(int[] evens)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nEvens:");
    foreach (var even in evens)
    {
        Console.Write(even + " ");
    }
}
```

and in the separate class doing the magic:

```
public int[] Odds
        {
            get
            {
                int count = 0;
                int[] odds = new int[NumArray.Length];
                string[] oddNums = {"1", "3", "5", "7", "9"};
                foreach (int num in NumArray)
                {
                    foreach (string oddNum in oddNums)
                    {
                        if (num.ToString().EndsWith(oddNum))
                        {
                            odds[count++] = num;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Array.Sort(odds);
                return RemoveDuplicates(odds);
            }
        }

        public int[] Evens
        {
            get
            {
                int count = 0;
                int[] evens = new int[NumArray.Length];
                string[] evenNum = {"0", "2", "4", "6", "8"};
                foreach (int num in NumArray)
                {
                    foreach (string oddNum in evenNum)
                    {
                        if (num.ToString().EndsWith(oddNum))
                        {
                            evens[count++] = num;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Array.Sort(evens);
                return RemoveDuplicates(evens);
            }
        }
```

Here is the RemoveDuplicates Method:

```
private int[] RemoveDuplicates(int[] numbers)
        {
            if (numbers.Length == 0)
            {
                return numbers;
            }
            int[] uniques = new int[numbers.Length];

            int previousVal = numbers[0];
            uniques[0] = numbers[0];
            int count = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == previousVal) continue;
                previousVal = numbers[i];
                uniques[count++] = numbers[i];
            }
            Array.Resize(ref uniques, count);
            return uniques;
        }
```

as an output i get(vvv), but i don't want the 0's at the beginning of them both, i don't want a 0 at all

[image]

Comment: It would make it a lot easier to help you if you would post a single short-but-complete example program, formatting it appropriately, rather than bits and pieces starting with code half way through a method.

Comment: *I input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1 to test it.*, it would be useful to include what the output is from that input and what you expected it to be.

Comment: Also, that's a pretty horrible way to determine if something is odd or even. Rather than relying on the last digit in a string, the easy way to deal with it is to convert your string to a number and then do `num%2`, which will be `0` if even and `1` if odd.

Comment: @MattBurland: Or -1 if it's odd and negative... I usually use `num & 1` instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Fair point, but I usually only test if `num%2 == 0`, so if odd is `1` or `-1` isn't a concern (if it's not even, then it's odd). But I do like the idea of `& 1`, I might have to use that from now on.

Comment: i didn't want to put the whole code because it is quite a big piece of code as there are other things that i am trying to gather from the array. I can add some more of the first bit of code i put in there if you want?

Comment: Also, as an aside (because again, I assume this is homework), there are better ways to remove duplicates from an array of `int`. Use [Enumerable.Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but i don't want the 0's at the beginning of them both, i don't want a 0 at all

Then you shouldn't create an array with 0s in, which is what you're doing.

Before you call `Array.Sort(odds)`, your array will have all the odd numbers from `NumArray`, followed by a bunch of 0 values (as many as there are even values in `NumArray`), because when you construct an array, it is automatically filled with the default value of the element type for each element. You'll only have no 0 values if the whole of `NumArray` is odd.

You only want as many elements as you need, so it would be better to use `List<int>`, and just add to that when you need to. You can call `ToArray()` to create an array at the end, if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Without the Array.Sort(odds) it puts the 0 at the end. I am putting it into an array, as it is a task that i have been assigned and it requires an array. This task also has other little task in it other than trying to find evens and odds, these others also need an array to work.

Comment: @Brendon: Sure, so create a `List<int>` with just what you need, and call `ToArray()` afterwards. Or change the rest of your code so that it's not as inflexible :)

Comment: So on that particular property, put NumArray into a List? and then call .ToArray() at the end?

Comment: @Brendon: No, not `NumArray` - but `odds` (and ditto for `evens`). Basically while you're building up the list of odd (or even) numbers.

Comment: oh ok i get it now, ill test that quick then ill get back to you thanks

Comment: @Brendon: If for some reason you cannot use `List` (because, I'm assuming this is some kind of homework assignment), then your alternative would be to resize you `odd` and `even` arrays *before* you sort them, thus removing the extra zeroes before the sort.

Comment: Thank you very much, that has worked perfectly. It has removed the zeros from the beginning. Thanks

Comment: I was ok to change the odds and evens array to a list it was just that i couldnt change NumArrays to a list that was where i was getting confused.

Answer (score -1):

When you're assigning values to the evens and odds arrays, you're using [count++] as the index. This means that it's never assigning index 0 and it'll have a default value of 0 from when the array was initialised.

Comment: Nope, `count++` will result in 0 for the first iteration, because it's a *post-increment*, not a *pre-increment*. The 0 values will be at the *end* of the array.

Comment: As Conrad pointed out, the only time post-increment and pre-increment are relevant is when displaying the values; in terms of logic it makes no difference.

Comment: Um, no. `count++` increments the variable but the result of the expression is the *original* value. Try it! `int[] x = new int[10]; int count = 0; x[count++] = 5; Console.WriteLine(x[0]);` That will print 5, so it *is* assigning to index 0.

Comment: @JohnClifford: post- vs pre- increment absolutely makes a difference. Not only when you display a value.

Comment: The count++ is to put the even or odd number in that place in the new array

Comment: Thanks trying anyay :)

Comment: Man, it must have been a longer day at work than I thought. I totally deserved that downvote: I reread this when I got home from the office and facepalmed at what an idiot I made myself look. Of course that isn't what caused it; I have code in MY OWN WORK PROJECTS that relies on pre/post-increment working exactly the opposite way that I said. My only defence is that I was so excited to finally be able to post something useful on SO. Sorry for wasting your time. XD

Comment: Haha don't worry about it we always have mistakes. You didn't waste my time don't worry xD.