# Forcing arithmetic precedence with syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, operator-precedence, post-increment, pre-increment

Every morning I get up grab my coffee and head on to SO to see what John Skeet has answered the day before.  It's my daily reminder that how much I don't know.  Today, for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681497/c-sharp-array-outputs-0-when-it-isnt-specified) there was a discussion on the increment operators such as `++` and `--`. The [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) says that `++` and `--` have higher precedence than `*`. Consider this code:

```
         int c = 10;
         c = c++ * --c;
```

and this code

```
        int c = 10;
        c = (c++) * (--c);
```

in both cases `c` is 100.  How would you force precedence (if possible at all) on this so the values in the parenthesis will be evaluated first before the multiplication?

Comment: If what you want is `(c + 1) * (c - 1)` then you should write it as such (*clearly*) instead of playing with pre and post increment/decrement of the same variable in the same statement.

Comment: pre and post increment decrement update same variable with value, while c+1 or c-1 is different thing

Comment: The question is not about style of the code.  The question is about the outcome of an operation.

Comment: It does. `c++` increment `c` so its value goes 11 and return 10 (postfix increment), then `--c` decrements `c` (11)  so its value goes 10 and return it (infix decrement) ,then 10 *10 = 100

Comment: Writing code like `c = c++;` is nonsensical. Just write `c = c + 2;` or `c++;` or whatever it is you actually mean.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I think you hit the nail right on the head

Comment: dont make things complex. its not a syntactic sugar. just google syntactic sugar and you get your answer. "_In computer science, syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express_" `c++ * --c;` is not easy to read or to understand. because you are misusing `++` and `--`

Comment: All you do is confusing yourself. Try using two different varaibles in the multiplication both initially set to 10 and observe.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary True but `++` and `--` are syntactic sugars.  And that's what I was referring to.

Comment: As a note `++` and `--` are prefix and postfix operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ++ after the variable will be applied only after the current instruction because it is a post increment.
Use ++ or -- before a variabile to achieve what you want

```
int c = 10;
c = ++c * --c ;
Console.WriteLine ( c ) ;
```

This code will output 110 because 10 + 1 = 11 and 11 - 1 = 10 so 10 * 11 = 110

Comment: Did you actually try it?

Comment: Yes, but i used Ideone.it to compile, because i have not visualstudio atm (but i not expect any surprises)

Answer (score 2):

Computers work on a stack of operations.

The following...

```
int c = 10;
c = c++ * --c;
```

is compiled into these operations...

```
//OpCode      // Function                                             Stack      Var c
ldc.i4.s   10 // 10 is pushed onto the stack                          {10}
stloc.0       // pop the stack and store the value in location 0      {}         10
ldloc.0       // location 0 is pushed onto the stack                  {10}       10
dup           // stack value is copied and pushed on stack            {10,10}    10
ldc.i4.1      // 1 is added to the stack                              {10,10,1}  10
add           // top 2 values are popped and the sum is pushed        {10, 11}   10
stloc.0       // pop the stack and store the value in location 0      {10}       11
ldloc.0       // location 0 is pushed onto the stack                  {10}       11
ldc.i4.1      // 1 is added to the stack                              {10,11,1}  11
sub           // top 2 values are popped and the difference is pushed {10, 10}   11
dup           // stack value is copied and pushed on stack            {10,10,10} 11
stloc.0       // pop the stack and store the value in location 0      {10,10}    10
mul           // top 2 values are popped and the product is pushed    {100}      10
stloc.0       // pop the stack and store the value in location 0      {}         100
ldloc.0       // location 0 is pushed onto the stack                  {100}      100
```

... I'm not sure that cleared anything up... but you can see while you were using the same variable everywhere (the stloc.0/ldloc.0) the actual operations work on the stack.  (what I have in the braces {}). Operations (dup, add, sub, and mul) don't care about the variable indexes just the stack.

And for giggles...

```
int c = 10;
c = ++c * c--;
```

... compiles into this...

```
//OpCode      // Function                                             Stack        Var c
ldc.i4.s   10 // 10 is pushed onto the stack                          {10}
stloc.0       // pop the stack and store the value in location 0      {}           10
ldloc.0       // location 0 is pushed onto the stack                  {10}         10
ldc.i4.1      // 1 is added to the stack                              {10,1}       10
add           // top 2 values are popped and the sum is pushed        {11}         10
dup           // stack value is copied and pushed on stack            {11,11}      10
stloc.0       // pop the stack and store the value in location 0      {11}         11
ldloc.0       // location 0 is pushed onto the stack                  {11,11}      11
dup           // stack value is copied and pushed on stack            {11,11,11}   11
ldc.i4.1      // 1 is added to the stack                              {11,11,11,1} 11
sub           // top 2 values are popped and the difference is pushed {11,11,10}   11
stloc.0       // pop the stack and store the value in location 0      {11,11}      10
mul           // top 2 values are popped and the product is pushed    {121}        10
stloc.0       // pop the stack and store the value in location 0      {}           121
ldloc.0       // location 0 is pushed onto the stack                  {121}        121
```

Comment: I'm glad you think so :) ...  confused myself for a minute.

Comment: BTW, if you move the pre/postfix operators around and look in ildasm you will see the `dup` operations move.